# Get authenticated user in django-tastypie

Tags: python, django, authentication, tastypie

I'm just starting with Python and Django, and using tastypie to create a RESTful API.

I need to calculate a field of a resource based on the authenticated user, I plan to override the dehydrate_field method in my resource, but I don't know how to get the authenticated user within the dehydrate_field method.

I'm using tastypie's ApiKeyAuthentication, and I'm currently passing the authentication parameters in the query string of the URL but I'd like to be able to pass the authentication parameters in the Authentication header too.

I think I should be able to get username from the query string or the Authorization header myself, and find the user with that, but I have a feeling like it has to be implemented in tastypie somewhere already, but I couldn't find it in the docs.

Here's some sample code:

```
class MyModelResource(ModelResource):

    calculated_field = fields.BooleanField(readonly=True)

    class Meta:
        queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'mymodel'
        authentication = ApiKeyAuthentication()     

    def dehydrate_calculated_field(self, bundle):
        user = <get authenticated user somehow>
        return <some boolean that's calculated depending on authenticated user>
```

I'd like to know if tastypie has some built-in functionality for getting the authenticated user or a proper way to roll my own, based on query string parameters or header fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer to the question, to get the current user I'm doing

```
user = bundle.request.user
```

Thanks to [Aidan Ewen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/795896/aidan-ewen) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with Tastypie, but I think a Tastypie Resource is a [django class based view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/class-based-views/). In which case you should be able to get the user with

`user = self.request.user`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, it didn't actually work though, but it helped me to know that I could get the user from the request, because **bundle** has a reference to the request (**not self**). See my answer for details.

Comment: Oh by the way, I'm not sure that a tastypie resource is a django class based view, can't find it in tastypie's docs and by checking the code [here](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py) I think it's not by line 65 `class Resource(object):`

Comment: Tastypie resource is not a class based view, or at least not yet. Tastypie was released before class based views were introduced. Also resource is not really a view in its essence because it handles urlconfig as well as views associated with them, hence by definition it's not really a view.

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation [miki725](http://stackoverflow.com/users/485844/miki725)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Per-Request Alterations To The Queryset](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#per-request-alterations-to-the-queryset)

```
class CurrentUserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'current-user'

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        users = super(CurrentUserResource, self).get_object_list(request)
        return users.filter(id=request.user.id)
```